# How to tell your boss that the reason for being late is because you set your alarm clock incorrectly?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Suppose you are an employee of a firm and you have a meeting tomorrow at 10 am and you set the alarm for 7 am but but you are very tired and you mistakenly set the alarm for 8 am. When you wake up next day, you take a look at the alarm clock, and get scared thinking how angry your boss will be and you have to explain this incident to your boss. How will you explain it?

I have tried but I think I am wrong

> I: sorry boss for being late.
>
> Boss: can I know what's the reason?
>
> I:Boss for me i set the alarm at 7 am but mistakenly i set it at 8 am cause of tiredness.

Editing is valid to above context

Comment: @MaulikV I think we cross edited :P

Comment: Exactly... lol.... i was scared at first! @Catija

Comment: I think that if you explained why you think your answer might not be right, it would improve your question. Is your concern about "sat the alarm" or "for me" or "tiredness"? Also, always capitalize "I".

Comment: This question is similar:  [How to excuse if we sleep more than we should](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49269)?

Answer (score 3):

You've got a good start.

You can start with an apology:

> Sorry for being late.
>
> I apologize for being late.

---

If your boss asks for an explanation, here are some ways of phrasing it that are clear and simple:

> I accidentally set my alarm for an hour later than I needed to.

In this case, the fact is that it was an accident... it doesn't really matter that you were really tired when you set your alarm and the exact times you set it for don't really matter, either.

You can also add the effect of the error (but it's not necessary):

> I accidentally set my alarm for an hour later than I needed to, so I wasn't able to catch the bus.
>
> I accidentally set my alarm for an hour later than I needed to and I got caught in really bad traffic.

---

If you want to explain more exactly, as you did in your example, you could say:

> I was exhausted when I set my alarm and accidentally set it for 8 am instead of 7 am.

---

Just make sure that whatever you say is in your own voice! If it sounds too natural, it may sound like a rehearsed excuse (and your boss may not believe you)... your example would certainly explain the situation clearly, it's just not a very natural way of saying it for a native speaker.

Comment: What about removing 'for' from this sentence: *I accidentally set my alarm for an hour later than I needed to.* Do you think it's required? If yes, why?

Comment: @MaulikV Yes, it's very helpful if not required... without it, it **could** mean that when you were doing the action of setting the clock, it was an hour later than it should have been (meaning you set the alarm at 11 pm instead of 10 pm). The listener would probably still understand what you mean but it's not clear.

Comment: I like your last suggestion (for the OP's 2nd line). I'd like to offer another alternative which uses only simple words: "I was very tired last night. I set my alarm for 8 (a.m.) instead of 7 (a.m.)!"

Answer (score 0):

There are ***many ways;*** I'm writing what I'd say...

> Sorry....just by mistake, instead of setting an alarm for 7 o'clock, I set it for 8. **So things got delayed.**

---

I'd recommend putting the bold sentence to prove your point of being delayed. That's because the boss does not know how much time you need to be at office. For him, it's the news that you put alarm at 7 to be at office by 10! :)

Comment: You didn't set the alarm **at** 8, you set it **for** 8. **At** is the time you did the setting (the night before). **For** is the time you set it to go off.

Comment: excellent! @Catija wow! Never thought of it. I'm correcting it. But **don't remove** this comment..it's so very useful! :)