# sorry if I made you rush into {replying / answering} to me back soon

Tags: sentence-construction, word-choice, clauses

Are these following sentences are idiomatic and suitable for formal letters ?
If none of them are idiomatic what would you say?

> 1.sorry if I made you rush into replying to me back soon but I was in a hurry.
>
> 2.sorry if I made you rush into answering to me back soon but I was in a hurry.
>
> 3.sorry for if I rushed you into answering to me back soon but I was in a hurry.
>
> 4.Sorry for making you rush into replying/ answering to me back soon but I was in a hurry.
>
> 5.Sorry for having you rush into replying/ answering to me back soon but I was in a hurry.
>
> 6.Sorry to rush you into replying/ answering to me back soon but I was in a hurry.

Comment: Be careful with apologies.  They can mean different things to different people, as discussed in [another ELL post](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49269).

Answer (score 4):

None of the choices are idiomatic.  None of them are formal.  None of them seem like sincere apologies.

It seems like all of these sentences are trying (and failing) to apologize for the following scenario:

- "I" asked "you" something.
- "you" either needed time to answer, or did not want to answer.
- "I was in a hurry."
- "I" rushed "you" into answering/replying.
- "you" answered.  "You" felt "rushed".  Maybe you gave a poor answer because you did not have enough time to give a good answer.  Maybe your feelings were unclear, so you did not want to give an answer.
- "I" am trying to explain why I "rushed" you.  Maybe I want to apologize for having rushed you.

In this scenario, in which the answer/reply has already been provided, **"soon" should be changed to "so soon" or "too soon"**.  "Soon" describes a time period, from when the request was made until it was answered.  The time the request was made is clear from the context.  "Soon" by itself is vague about when the answer is provided, so it implies that the answer/reply has not yet been sent.  "So soon" implies that both the start and the end of the time period are known, so it is consistent with either the answer/reply already having been sent, or with a clear expectation for when the answer/reply is desired.  "Too soon" means "sooner than optimal".

**The sentence should start with a capital letter.**

**There should be a comma after "soon",** to separate the apology clause from the excuse clause.

**Either "replying" or "answering" is acceptable.**  Which word is better?  That depends on whether the response actually answered the question.  "Replying" is more formal, but vaguer than "answering".  One "answers" a question.  A "reply" is a response, but it might avoid providing a useful answer.

**Either "replying to" or "answering" (without the "to") is acceptable.**  One replies to a message, or answers a question.  Saying "Sully answers to Bob" describes a relationship where Bob is the boss, and Sully is the subordinate.

**The "to me" or "me" is probably unnecessary.**  If it is (or was) unclear whom "you" should reply to, then the "to me" or "me" is useful.

**The word "back" is redundant.**  When replying to someone, one might "write back" or "call back".  The words "reply" and "answer" are in response to a question that was put forth, so they include the idea of "back".

**"For" and "if" are contradictory** in this context.  If you are "sorry for" something, you are not wondering if you did that thing.

After making these corrections, the original post's choices become:

> 1a.  Sorry if I made you rush into replying too soon, but I was in a hurry.
>
> 2b.  Sorry if I made you rush into answering too soon, but I was in a hurry.
>
> 4b.  Sorry for making you rush into replying so soon, but I was in a hurry.
>
> 4c.  Sorry for making you rush into answering so soon, but I was in a hurry.
>
> 5b.  Sorry for having you rush into replying so soon, but I was in a hurry.
>
> 5c.  Sorry for having you rush into answering so soon, but I was in a hurry.
>
> 6b.  Sorry to rush you into replying so soon, but I was in a hurry.
>
> 6c.  Sorry to rush you into answering so soon, but I was in a hurry.

**A clear apology is stronger than an "iffy" apology.**

**"Making" is clearer than "having"**, in this context.

If "I" am apologizing, "I" should be clear that "I" am at fault.  Thus, **it is better to say "I am sorry" than to skip straight to the word "sorry".**  Making the apology into a full sentence is also more formal.

The word "but" tends to negate the words that came before it.  In this context, it emphasizes the excuse.  **Eliminating the conjunction "but" (and making the excuse into a separate sentence) emphasizes the apology.**

**An apology that uses the active voice is stronger than an apology that uses the passive voice.**  Thus, "I rushed you" is clearer than "to rush you".

In this context, **"quickly" might be appropriate instead of "soon".**

Here are two options that include these corrections:

> 4d.  I am sorry for making you rush into replying so quickly.  I was in a hurry.
>
> 6e.  I am sorry I rushed you into answering so soon.  I was in a hurry.

**"I was in a hurry" is not very formal.**  (But it is honest!)

Comment: what would your choice be?

Comment: Excellent reply by @Jasper! Amanda21, I would go with 6e as it seems to be most precise and yet conveys exactly what you intend to.